# reverse every word of the sentence..the changes do not appear

Tags: java

this is a simple program to reverse each word of the string  and print ... i dont know whats going wrong with this...please help

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ReverseWordCapitalizeFirstCharacter {


    public static void reverse(char a[], int start, int  end)
    {   
        while(start<end)
        {
        char temp = a[start];
        a[start] = a[end];
        a[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.next();

        char a[] = new char[str.length()];
        a = str.toCharArray();
        int wordStartIndex = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        {
                if(a[i] == ' ')
                {  
                    reverse(a,wordStartIndex,i-1);  
                     wordStartIndex = i+1;
                }

        }

        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

i am passing the character array as parameter to the function that reverse each word..

Comment: Did you try to use the debugger? My guess is that you never call `reverse()`

Comment: Just a wild guess, bet you know how to program in C or C++.  Am I right?  ;)

Comment: new StringBuilder(hi).reverse().toString()

Comment: @yogaranjan It shows for your love of char arrays.  I rarely have to deal with chars directly in my programs.  Standard library support for java is wonderful and in my experience, there almost always exists ways to do relatively simple tasks without having to write it yourself.

Comment: @Neil It is a tradeoff between simplicity and efficiency. At school, I would use the OP's solution because it is cleaner but at work, I would not hesitate to prefer a one-line solution such as `new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString()` which is worse for memory but far less error prone.

Comment: @Neil - you'r right..library methods would have made it much simpler...i just wanted to play a little with loops..

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle You're right of course.  The tendency with Java is that since you didn't pick Java for performance, you're allowed a little leeway to write clearer code instead whereas in C++, you tended to just prefer the faster, even if it looked uglier.  They're microoptimizations anyway.  So long as you're not changing algorithm big O notation.

Comment: FYI: use code points instead of characters, You don't want to break emoji's  that use a skin modifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not because sc.next() returns only the next word ? 
So, you never encounter a ' ' in your string, thus you never call the reverse method. Try with sc.nextLine(); maybe.

Answer (score 1):

[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) says :

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

As a result, if you enter `"abc 123 456"`, `sc.next()` will only return `"abc"`.

```
String str = sc.next();//str only contains "abc"

[...]

if(a[i] == ' ') //This condition is never met.
```

You can specify the delimiter like this :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter("\n");
```